# How to merge 2 flv files with alpha channel?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am a new face in flash community. May I have some suggestion from you guys?

I have 2 flv files, one is a video with alpha channel (I want to show it on the top), and the recorded file from camera on mobile device (maybe on iOS device). How should I do, If I want to merge these files together by programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand correctly, but I think you want to show 2 video at same position.

It's pretty easy. You should start a new project, and import the two videos:

```
var myVideo:Video = new Video();
addChild(myVideo);
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
myVideo.attachNetStream(ns);
ns.play("http://www.example.com/file.flv");

var myVideo2:Video = new Video();
addChild(myVideo2);
var nc2:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc2.connect(null);
var ns2:NetStream = new NetStream(nc2);
myVideo2.attachNetStream(ns2);
ns2.play("http://www.example.com/file2.flv");
```

Than you should set the alpha (opacity) to 0.5 (or anything in a 0-1 range) of the video, so it will be semi-transparent:

```
myVideo2.alpha = 0.5;
```

The child you added last with addChild() will be on top of the displaylist, so you should set the alpha of that one. (you can also set both's alpha to any value).

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you.
I can show 2 video files in the same position, but the video in top layer has an alpha channel that can see the bottom one.

I want to export them as one flv file, How should I do?

Comment: oh, you want to export them? sorry, i didn't get that. Then you need to edit the 2 flv-s (like in Adobe After Effects, or any free software), and then convert it back to flv.. you don't even need flash for that..